# Network unreachable after adding new bridged interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, lxc

I am trying to add new bridged interface in /etc/network/interfaces with following settings on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM while testing LXC containers.

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

After starting the br0, VM is not able to access the network. If I comment these and restart the VM then it can access the network.

Thanks for any help in advance!